# "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context " On creating web api2 in Individual User Accounts in Web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have the following code in AccountsController.cs

```
    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Now when i do postman call for this api with api/Account/Register Link with email password and Confirm Password fields then it is showing error as follows

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)\r\n
```

Can any one help me out with this thing

Comment: What does your context look like? I'm guessing it's not inheriting from the correct type, specifically the wrong generic user type. Either that or you have 2 `ApplicationUser` classes in your project.

Comment: No DavidG I have only 1 ApplicationUser class in the project. It is inheriting IdentityUser

Comment: And what does the context look like?